# Awesomium.NET - не срабатывает ExecuteJavascript()

Tags: .net, awesomium

Застрял на пустом месте...

Вот WebControl, который построил Джек

```
private Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl webControl1;
```

Вот бинд, который повешан на WebControl, который построил Джек

```
this.webControl1.DocumentReady += new Awesomium.Core.UrlEventHandler(this.load_points);
```

Вот функция, которая вяжется в бинд, который повешан на WebControl, который построил Джек

```
private void load_points(object sender, Awesomium.Core.UrlEventArgs e)
    {

    ...more code..
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("call js");
            webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("testt(" + reader["name"] + ")");

        }
    }
```

Вот вывод в консоль, который пишет функция, которая вяжется в бинд, который повешан на WebControl, который построил Джек

```
call js
call js
...more call js...
```

Вот функция, которая должна вызываться (js)

```
function testt(str){
        $('#coords').html(str)
        alert(str)
}
```

**Но не алерта, не замены текста я не наблюдаю..**

Предыдущий код вызывал эту функцию без проблем, но при очередной переустановке Виндоуз я его не сохранил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, не хватает кавычек:

```
webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("testt('" + reader["name"] + "')");
```